# Publish to current users wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I wrote a small Facebook Ap[p in PHP and would like to be able to post a message to the current user's Facebook wall. The app is set to use FBML. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stream.publish`.  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

There are lots of options you can pass into it.  The most important one to learn to use correctly is the Attachment, which is how you set the description, body, and image associated with a wall post: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments

Comment: Thanks. I'd been looking for a while and couldn't find anything. +1 for you!